# Name of this Plant - Yellow center and edges Green

Tags: identification, houseplants

Bought this plant 4 months but dont know the name of this plant but still i repotted it and i water it after 2 weeks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Euonymus is not normally considered  a house plant. Lower light levels will reduce the variegation. I would expect this plant to get lanky and stretched out over time

Comment: It was cloudy here when i took picture otherwise it is on very bright spot. But i will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it is a *Euonymus japonicus 'Aurea'*. See my answer here for more details:
[What variety of euonymus is this?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/44257/what-variety-of-euonymus-is-this)

In this case, I think that part of the plant has reverted back to its non-variegated (and IMHO more attractive) ancestry.

Comment: Yup definitely looks like the one you linked. Thanks